# Good practice escaping multiple strings

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

Is this good practice when escaping multiple strings at once, strings which are coming from a POST or GET?

Is there something else I should think about or do different? I now there is PDO but in this code I don't want to use it.

```
class Bo extends Db
{
    function clean($cThis)
    {
        $res = array();
        foreach (array_keys($cThis) as $key) {
            $res[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($cThis[$key]));
        }
        return $res;
    }

    function add($info)
    {
        $this->dbConnect();
        $cInfo = $this->clean($info);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (b, c) VALUES ('".$cInfo['b']."', '".$cInfo['c']."')");
        $this->dbDisconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). +1 to @alnitak for his answer.

Comment: You don't want to use `addslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Delete the `addslashes()`. Also, ensure `magic_quotes_gpc` is not on.

Comment: @vascowhite FWIW, I would always go for PDO over MySQLi so that I'm not constrained to using MySQL for the backend.

Comment: @Alnitak I agree, but I don't want to be too religious about it :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams thanks for answer! Okay, but when looking at what have bened inserted to the database after removing addslashes() this string: 'bobo' is outputed as stated ('bobo') and not \'bobo\'. But this is okay and don't mess with the mysql_query statement? (Just double-checking)

Comment: @Robert, it's working then. Though the escape characters are stored, MySQL converts the escaped sequences back to normal when sending the values.

Answer (score 4):

Good practise is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), *not* manually escaping strings and concatenating them into a query, e.g.:

```
$db = DB::connect($dsn);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (b, c) VALUES (?, ?)");
$res = $sth->execute(array($info['b'], $info['c']));
$db->disconnect()
```

Oh, and make sure `gpc_magic_quotes` is disabled, too!

Comment: Yes, PDO is always good. But if we play with the thought that PDO doesn't exists. Or maybe look at it this way. Is there anything that could slip through my check? Like something i forgot (regarding the clean function)?

Comment: @Robert no, go straight to jail, do not pass go, etc, etc.  Or, in other words - do not _ever, ever, ever_ use the raw `mysql_*` functions.  You should assume that _those_ do not exist, for pain and suffering and SQL injection attacks will follow for all those that do not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I say it this way instead. The company Im about to work at want to se how I escape strings without using PDO and just using mysql_*. They are not high-tech of course. This is the way they want it and I have nothing to say about it. With that said. Is this a good (as good as it gets without PDO) way of handling that?

Comment: @Robert if this is by way of an interview question and this is their _current_ coding standard, then run, very far, and _very_ fast.  You really don't want to end up on thedailywtf.com

Comment: @Robert tell them that the mysql_ functions are no longer best practice and that you would use prepared statements.

Comment: I will. But still that doesn't solve my question Im afraid. I dont now how to wright further to just focus the attention to my problem and not PDO/MySQLi suggestions. I really appreciate it, dont get me wrong. But I have to send over test code in about 2h and they want it this way. No, nada, finito, natacho other way. They are the shepherd and Im the sheep.

Comment: @Robert are you sure that isn't part of the test - to demonstrate that you know that `mysql_*` is old fashioned, insecure, and never to be used in modern code?

Comment: @Robert I'm afraid you won't get help from good programmers to develop poor code.

Comment: @Alnitak yes, haha. Just take me on my words, please :) [@]vascowhite thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Robert you should at least pay attention to MarcusAdams comments in the question - your code is currently doing _too much_.  It might also be doing too little - that's the problem with PHP and `mysql_real_escape_string` - you never can tell...

Comment: @Alnitak I had missed that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The PDO would be the best choice, but in case you don't have it. There're some methods that mimic the `pg_query_params` for mysql. It is written as methods of a class, `$this->dbconn` is the connection resource returned by `mysqli_init`. Of course you may change the `mysqli` methods with the appropriate `mysql` analogs.

```
/**
 * Returns the single value of the array mysqli_query_params__parameters
 *
 * @param $at the position of the parameter inside the array mysqli_query_params__parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function mysqli_query_params__callback( $at )
{
    return $this->mysqli_query_params__parameters[ $at[1]-1 ];
}

/**
 * Parameterised query implementation for MySQL (similar PostgreSQL's PHP function pg_query_params)
 * Example: mysqli_query_params( "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1=$1 AND col2=$2", array( 42, "It's ok" ), $dbconn );
 *
 * @param $query, $parameters, $datadase
 * @return mixed(resorce, false)
 * @access public
 */
public function mysqli_query_params( $query, $parameters=array(), $database=false )
{
    if( !is_array($parameters) ){
        return false;
    } else {
        if($this->is_assoc($parameters)){
            $parameters = array_values($parameters);
        }
    }

    // Escape parameters as required & build parameters for callback function
    foreach( $parameters as $k=>$v )
    {
        $parameters[$k] = ( is_int( $v ) ? $v : ( NULL===$v ? 'NULL' : "'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbconn, $v )."'" ) );
    }
    $this->mysqli_query_params__parameters = $parameters;

    // Call using mysqli_query
    if( false === $database )
    {
        $query = preg_replace_callback( '/\$([0-9]+)/', array($this, 'mysqli_query_params__callback'), $query );
        $result = mysqli_query( $this->dbconn, $query );

        if( false === $result )
        {
            $err_msg = mysqli_error($this->dbconn);
            return false;
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $query = preg_replace_callback( '/\$([0-9]+)/', array($this, 'mysqli_query_params__callback'), $query );
        $result = mysqli_query( $this->dbconn, $query, $database );

        if( false === $result )
        {
            $err_msg = mysqli_error($this->dbconn);

            return false;
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```